# Select a variable to output from within stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a stored procedure I've started coding and need to return a value.  In SQL Server I could just do a SELECT of the variable to return it.  However this does not seem to work with Teradata and have not found a similar example on how to do this.  Here is my stored procedure:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Get_MyValue()
BEGIN
DECLARE mytestvar  VARCHAR(40);
SELECT mycolumn INTO mytestvar FROM MyTable;
SELECT mytestvar;
END;
```

I get this error:

> STATEMENT 2: REPLACE  failed.  Failed [5526 : HY000] Stored Procedure
>   is not created/replaced due to error(s).{Nested Failure Msg [5526 :
>   HY000] SPL1045:E(L10), Invalid or missing INTO clause.}

I also tried adding an OUT variable to the procedure but that did not work either:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Get_MyValue(mytestvarout VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
DECLARE mytestvar  VARCHAR(40);
SELECT mycolumn INTO mytestvar FROM MyTable;
END;
```

With this error:

> Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5531 : HY000] Named-list is not
>   supported for arguments of a procedure.  Elapsed time = 00:00:00.079

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return a single row you must define and OUT-variable and assign a value to it:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Get_MyValue(OUT mytestvarout VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
  DECLARE mytestvar  VARCHAR(40);
  SELECT mycolumn INTO mytestvar FROM MyTable;
  SET mytestvarout = mytestvar;
END;
```

To return a result set you need to define a kind of dummy-cursor (blame Standard SQL :-)

[Returning Result Sets from a Stored Procedure](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1148-160K/laf1472241407163.html#)

Comment: I'm getting this error still: Named-list is not supported for arguments of a procedure.

Comment: You need to CALL it with a parameter name: `CALL sp_Get_MyValue(whatever)` (usually you use the actual variable name instead of `whatever`)